# How to loop over multiple tr's with *ngFor without using ng-template and ng-container?

Tags: angular2-template

```
  <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Desc</th>
             </tr>
          </thead>

          <tbody>
            <ng-container *ngFor="let prospect of listData;let rowIndex=index;">
           <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>

            </tr>
            <tr *ngIf="IsOpen">
                <td colspan="2">
                  <div>
                    Edit template
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
           </ng-container>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

Currently I am using ng-container to create consecutive rows but I am getting issues when I use ng2-dragula over ng-container. Please suggest any other way around to create these two rows for each item in listData.

Answer (score 0):

make a component for this part:

```
`<tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>

        </tr>
        <tr *ngIf="IsOpen">
            <td colspan="2">
              <div>
                Edit template
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
```

`

and then do `ngFor` on it:

`<tbody>
            <prospect [isOpen]="IsOpen" *ngFor="let prospect of listData;let rowIndex=index;">
           </prospect>
</tbody>`

you can add input (for example `prospect`) and output as you need.